# Create Dynamic Table phpdocx

Tags: phpword, phpdocx

I have a template, with variables and i need to create and add a dynamic table on this file without a declared variable on the template. I´m trying to use this code

```
 private function arquivo_desonerado($infos, $ncmDados = NULL) {
    require_once '../Vendor/phpdocx/classes/CreateDocx.inc';
    require_once '../Vendor/phpdocx/classes/TransformDoc.inc';
    $docx = new CreateDocx();
    $pdf = new TransformDoc();
    $docx->enableCompatibilityMode();
    $docx->addTemplate("arquivo/desoneracao/enquadrados.docx");
    $ncms = $total = $desonerado = array();

    foreach ($ncmDados as $dados) {
        $ncms[] = (String)$dados['ncm'];
        $total[] = (String)$dados['total'];
        $desonerado[] = (String)$dados['desonerado'];
    }

    ... 

    $docx->addTable(array($ncms,$total,$desonerado));
    $docx->createDocx("arquivo/enquadrados");
```

No error is displayed.

Someone can help me?

Comment: is $docx an instance of CreateDocx? Are you using $docx->createDocx('path') in the end?

Comment: Yes, it´s an instance. Yes, i´m using, i completed the example code.

Comment: if you try code in the example, I mean just using the same files examples provide, it works? If so, problem is in your data. Unfortunately, the way that library provides information to dev user is somewhat poor

Answer (score 0):

I think this example is what you are looking for if you want to add a base table in your template

http://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/templates/replace-table-variable-Word-document

you basically setup single variables and then can create as many rows as you wish.

if you don't want to add it to your template the table will be added to very end of document and your code should work fine. But I think the issue is that function enableCompatibilityMode() doesn't exist so you need to get rid of it.